# Django Custom login using email not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, jinja2

I am trying to log a user in via email in django, everything is working fine(code wise), no errors and functions execute in a right manner. However, when I perform a check in the template it always return false.

Here is my code:

```
authenticate_user.py

def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
    try:
      user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Email or Password is not correct.')
      print("User not found")
      return None
    else:
      user_password_is_valid = check_password(password, user.password)
      if user_password_is_valid:
        print("User found")
        return user
      else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Email or Password is not correct.')
        return None
    return None
```

And for the `handle_login` view:

```
def handle_login(request):
  context= {
    'title': 'Login'
  }
  if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
    print('User is', user)
    # This prints user no problem
    if user is not None:
      login(request, user)
      # No errors up to this point
      return redirect(reverse('mainapp:homepage'))
    else:
      return redirect(reverse('mainapp:homepage'))
```

Now upon checking -> `{% user.is_authenticated %}` in the `template.html` it always return false.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further checking, I realized that the problem was at:

```
def get_user(self, email):
    try:
      return User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      return None
```

It should be:

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
      return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
      return None
```

However, I am not still sure how the behavior of `get_user()` work.